# Alternative to \substack{} for a related purpose

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I would like to write something like the following, but involves mathematical symbols:
[image: Word Sucks]

I tried using the `\substack{}` but it makes the font smaller. I'd like a novel alternative to achieve this.

And, thank you TeX.SX users for being helpful !

**Edit:** I have received wonderful answers here, as is true of many of my other questions. I have chosen the answer whose code I am using now. I sincerely wish I could upvote answers several times and accept several answers. `:-(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a somewhat simpler solution you could use something like

```
\begin{align*}
\begin{Bmatrix}
& \text{hi}  \\
& \text{hello}
\end{Bmatrix}
\longleftrightarrow
\begin{Bmatrix}
& \text{The droids} \\
& \text{lorrem lipsum}
\end{Bmatrix}
\end{align*}
```

to get the exact arrow style you would have to use tikz and the arrows libary.

Comment: I have chosen this answer as this is the one I am currently using.

Answer (score 7):

Just use `tabular` for the text, or replace `tabular` with `array` for mathematics. You could also consider the `Bmatrix` environment from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) for the latter case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\left\{ 
\begin{tabular}{c}
TeX.SX users that \\
ask questions on \\
this site
\end{tabular}
\right\}
\longleftrightarrow
\left\{ 
\begin{tabular}{c}
TeX users in the \\
world using \\
TeX.SX
\end{tabular}
\right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

here are two possibilities, using `amsmath`.  the spacing inside the braces is different, which may influence your preference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
 \left\{
  \begin{array}{c}
   a + b\\
   c + d\\
   e + f
  \end{array}
 \right\}
\quad\longleftrightarrow\quad
 \left\{
  \begin{array}{c}
   g + h\\
   i + j\\
   k + l
  \end{array}
 \right\}
\]

\[
 \begin{Bmatrix}
   a + b\\
   c + d\\
   e + f
 \end{Bmatrix}
\quad\longleftrightarrow\quad
 \begin{Bmatrix}
   g + h\\
   i + j\\
   k + l
 \end{Bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

and the output:

[image]